# Multiple if function excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please let me know if there is any function to bring in the attached file in a different table, all the serial numbers for device A from order 112 delivered in UK without using pivots.
What I need is to bring me in I2 SN 1001 and 1004 which match to device A from order 112 delivered in UK

[image]

```
Order   Device  SN  Delivered to
112 A   1001    UK
112 B   1002    US
112 A   1003    ITALY
112 A   1004    UK
223 A   1005    UK
223 A   1006    FRANCE
223 C   1007    UK
223 D   1008    UK
441 B   1009    UK
441 D   1010    FRANCE
441 B   1011    UK
441 A   1012    UK
```

Comment: Sorry, what value do you expect to exist in cell `I2`?

Comment: Hi Dave, I need all the serial numbers from column C for device A delivered in UK for order 112

Comment: Why can't you use a pivot table? It will probably be the easiest. Or VBa

Comment: I need to bring me in I2 SN 1001 and 1004 which match to device A from order 112 delivered in UK. I hope I made myself more clear :(

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/1093077/edit) and explain what you expect in `I2`. Examples like that will help us to understand the situation :) Also please explain why you are not able to use Pivot Tables

Comment: Thank you Dave. If there is no other way I will use a pivot.

Comment: Well, there are other ways, such as VBa. I'm just not convinced you won't be better off with a pivot table. Do you know or want a VBa solution?

Comment: yes, please, I don't know what VBa is

Comment: Then the answer is learn pivot tables.

Comment: If you are averse to pivot tables, you can do this kind of thing with a helper column.  In the helper column, put the concatenation of the Order, Device, and Delivered To columns.  So if you use col E, E2 would be =A2&B2&D2.  Now you can use simple lookup tools on col E to find the relevant records.

Comment: If you are using the latest office 365 then it can be done with the TEXTJOIN() Function.

Comment: What you should do is copy the data to new sheets, one for each new "deliver to". If you want each country to be view-able. Or else you can just filter this sheet as it is on the table on the left. If you refuse to use a filter then you will have to write a program in VB to search the data. Also if you refuse to use a filter, you'd be better off using an Access database and perform queries on the data.

Answer (score 0):

There are list aggregate functions if you are using a database. With Excel, the best bet is a Pivot Table.

I ordered the rows by Country, Order, then Serial number. The column is Device. The data is a count of Device.

[image]

If you want a [listagg function for Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261390/creating-a-flattened-list-from-a-rowset), you'll have to use a third party tool.